# In ELB when load becomes normal from high which ec2 instance terminate first?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have a auto scaling group in my ec2 , that is whenever cpu usage is 50% then a new instance launched automatically.

There is a point come in my mind that when the load becomes normal which ec2 instance terminate first, Is there is fifo approach or what?

Answer (score 0):

The instances are terminated by the Auto-Scaling Group, not the Load Balancer. The behavior, and ability to customize the Auto-Scaling Group termination behavior, is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html).